# How can I deploy MsSQL LocalDB with my UWP app?

Tags: entity-framework, uwp, localdb

I am currently developing an UWP app. It uses EF Core and I store my data in MsSQL LocalDB database.
My question is: how can I ship the MsSQL LocalDB with my UWP app (through the Microsoft Store)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can, best option is to share a link to the download from your app.